# OpenGL +SFML + GLFW3

Tags: opengl, sfml, glfw

I'am maybe asking a stupid question, but can we mix OpenGl + SMFL and add to it some GLFW in the same SFML window ?

Comment: I really don't know why you would want to do this.  The point of libraries like GLFW is to provide windowing and input without the baggage of advanced drawing and sound functionality.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-opengl.php) is a link on how mix openGL code with the SFML, are you sure that the GLFW feature that you are looking for, aren't on the sfml already, because in my experience there is no reasone for mix up this two library.